# MySQL 5.6 Tablespace views are empty

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 5.6 machine running on Redhat 6 and for some reason, all the views for tablespaces are empty.  For example, I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_tablespaces;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_tablespaces;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_datafiles;
```

I have a few other machines also running MySQL 5.6 that should have been set up identically that provide data for each query.  Any idea what this would be?

Edit: Looking at it further, it was discovered adding new tables creates new tablespaces since the setting for "File-Per-Table" is set.  However, even though all the other tables still exist, MySQL still doesn't show the other tablespaces.

Comment: Maybe you use different storage engine like `MyISAM`

Comment: @lad2025 Looking at this machine and others using information_schema.tables, I see they're all using MyISAM for the engine so that doesn't seem to be an issue.